# Targeting Colors from an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, loops

In this project I want a color that I choose to be tracked by a box. The problem with my code is that it would only track one of the colors even if there are two of the same colors on the stage. If you can help me out Thank you every much.

**Main.as**

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;

[SWF(frameRate='31', width='1000', height='500')]

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var balls:Array;
        private var directions:Array = [new Point(-1,-1),new Point(0,-1),new Point(1,-1),
                                        new Point(-1,0),new Point(1,0),
                                        new Point(-1,1),new Point(0,1),new Point(1,1)
                                        ];

        private var ballNum: Number = 10;
        private var ball:Ball;
        private var box:Box;

        /*private var padding:Number = 20;

        private var ay:Number = 5;
        private var gravity:Number = 6;
        private var bounce:Number = -0.9;
        */

        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void
        {
            balls = new Array();

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < ballNum; i++)
            {
                ball = new Ball(Math.random() * 30);

                ball.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                ball.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                ball.direction = directions[Math.floor(Math.random()*directions.length)];
                addChild(ball);

                balls.push(ball);
            }

            box = new Box();
            addChild(box);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
            {
                balls[i].x += balls[i].direction.x;
                balls[i].y += balls[i].direction.y;

                if (balls[i].colors == 0x79DCF4) {
                    box.x = balls[i].x - box.width / 2;
                    box.y = balls[i].y - box.height / 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Ball.as**

```
package{

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Ball extends Sprite
    {
        public var colors:Array = [0xFFFF33, 0xa5a5a5, 0x79DCF4, 0xFF3333, 0xFFCC33, 0x99CC33];
        public var color:uint;
        public var radius:Number;
        public var direction:Point;

        public function Ball(radius:Number = 15, color:uint = 0xcccccc)
        {
            this.color = colors[randomColor(0, colors.length - 1)];
            this.radius = radius;

            init();
        }
        private function randomColor(min:Number, max:Number):Number
        {
            var randomNumber:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
            return randomNumber;
        }

        private function init():void
        {
            graphics.beginFill(color);
            graphics.drawCircle(0,0,radius);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to track color, not colors

So change this line

```
if (balls[i].colors == 0x79DCF4) {
```

to

```
if (balls[i].color == 0x79DCF4) {
```

Try to track one ball in each frame

```
    private var blueBalls:Array = [];//to save the blue balls

    private function init():void
    {
        balls = new Array();

        for(var i:Number = 0; i < ballNum; i++)
        {
            ball = new Ball(Math.random() * 30);

            ball.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            ball.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
            ball.direction = directions[Math.floor(Math.random()*directions.length)];
            addChild(ball);

            balls.push(ball);

            if (ball.color == 0x79DCF4) {
                blueBalls.push(ball);
            }
        }

        box = new Box();
        addChild(box);

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }

    private var lastBlueBallIndex:int = -1;//save which blue ball has been tracked in blueballs

    private var hasFind:Boolean = false;

    private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        hasFind = false;

        for(var i:int = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
        {
            balls[i].x += balls[i].direction.x;
            balls[i].y += balls[i].direction.y;

            var index:int = blueBalls.indexOf(balls[i]);

            if (index != -1 && !hasFind ) {

                //here is the main part, when reach last blue ball, reset lastBlueBallIndex 
                if (index == blueBalls.length - 1) {//if get last blue ball
                    lastBlueBallIndex = -1;
                } else if (lastBlueBallIndex  >= index) {//if the ball has been tracked
                    continue;
                } else {
                    lastBlueBallIndex = index;//set the current ball index
                }

                hasFind  = true;

                box.x = balls[i].x - box.width / 2;
                box.y = balls[i].y - box.height / 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

use a timer instead of ENTER_FRAME  , remember to remove  Event.ENTER_FRAME listerer.

```
private function init():void {

    /*the old code*/


    var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);//set the interval time longger if you want
    // you can change onEnterFrame to another name, like onTimer
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onEnterFrame);
    timer.start();

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, there's still a problem. It is still only tracking one blue ball.

Comment: I have edit the answer. If you want to track different blue balls, you can't do that in one frame.You can track one in each frame.

Comment: thanks again, but it is still only tracking one of the blue balls

Comment: I have edit the answer and fix the syntax and logic error. I have test the code and it works.

Comment: thank you so much it works,But the boxes are blinking once there tracking the ball.

Comment: It's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Have you removed this line addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);?　If you have removed this line and it still not work, try to set 1000 to bigger, like 3000